# How to make a triply nested map

Tags: arrays, dictionary, go, ldap, maps

I'm trying to create a triply nested map in order to store some LDAP information, but having an issue with some of the data. Here's a working triply nested map:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var data = map[string]interface{}{}
    data["name"] = "User"
    data["info"] = map[string]interface{}{}
    data["info"].(map[string]interface{})["email"] = "user@mail.com"


    data["info"].(map[string]interface{})["objectClass"] = map[interface{}]interface{}{}

  data["info"].(map[string]interface{})["objectClass"].(map[interface{}]interface{})["0"] = "top"

  data["info"].(map[string]interface{})["objectClass"].(map[interface{}]interface{})[1] = "shadowPosix"


    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

However, when I try to format some of the data according to my LDAP data, there becomes an error that says:
`panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not map[string]interface {}`

Here is the code I am using that does not work:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var data = map[string]interface{}{}
    data["name"] = "User"

    data["CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=dev,DC=io"] = map[string]interface{}{}
    data["CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=dev,DC=io"].(map[string]interface{})["email"] = "user@mail.com"


    data["info"].(map[string]interface{})["objectClass"] = map[interface{}]interface{}{}

  data["info"].(map[string]interface{})["objectClass"].(map[interface{}]interface{})["0"] = "top"

  data["info"].(map[string]interface{})["objectClass"].(map[interface{}]interface{})[1] = "shadowPosix"


    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

The only difference are the 2 lines after data["name"] = "User".

Comment: You never initialized `data["info"]` in the second snippet. As a side note, this is terribly complicated for a simple task. Use structs.

Comment: Ah, that's where it is. Thank you. How would I use structs for this?

Comment: Every map[string]interface{} can be replaced with struct that has fields matching the keys of the map, and field types decided based on the type of the value of the map.

Comment: Don't use `interface{}`.